# why my combobox in imgui-rs is always shows the first element in array?

Tags: rust, combobox, imgui

```
                            let items = vec![
                                "Example0",
                                "Example1",
                                "Example2",
                                "Example3",
                                "Example4",
                                "Example5",
                                "Example6"
                            ];
                            let mut selected = &items[0];
                            if let Some(cb) = ui.begin_combo(" ", selected) {
                                for cur in &items {
                                    if selected == cur {
                                        // Auto-scroll to selected item
                                        ui.set_item_default_focus();
                                    }
                                    // Create a "selectable"
                                    let clicked = ui.selectable_config(cur)
                                        .selected(selected == cur)
                                        .build();
                                    // When item is clicked, store it
                                    if clicked {
                                        selected = cur;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

when I click on `Example2` it shows the `Example0`
how should I fix that to change the value when I click the selected item.

tried changing functions (ui.combo) or (ui.combo_simple_string)

Comment: Your `selected` is a local variable which you reset each time you display the GUI. You should move it to the application state so that it will persist between frames.

Comment: this code is an example of the rust imgui docs

Comment: Hey Richard, I think you should read how to ask a question and reformulate yours so that other members can better assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question was not not well formulated, did not give any context